# Get value from previous row data for next datas by dates

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table 2 transactions let's say table A and B, for some cases i need to transfer row datas from table B to A as new table with several conditions :

- The price for the data transferred will follow from the previous data
- The same date will not processed into results
- When there is no previous data, it will not processed into results

For Example :

```
    -----------Table A-------------      ----------Table B---------- 
    product |   Date      | Price |      | Product  |     Date     |  
       A    | 2019-01-01  |  10   |      |    A     |  2018-11-05  |
       A    | 2019-01-15  |  15   |      |    A     |  2019-01-10  |
       A    | 2019-01-25  |  20   |      |    A     |  2019-01-12  |
       A    | 2019-05-01  |  25   |      |    A     |  2019-01-27  |
       A    | 2019-07-02  |  30   |      |    B     |  2019-02-10  |
       B    | 2019-02-05  |  40   |      |    B     |  2019-04-22  |
       B    | 2019-04-22  |  50   |      |    B     |  2019-05-13  |
       B    | 2019-05-12  |  40   |
```

Result :

```
         -----------Table C-------------      
        product |   Date      | Price |      
           A    | 2019-01-01  |  10   |      
           A    | 2019-01-10  |  10   |  *The prices follow the data in the previous date (2019-01-01)
           A    | 2019-01-12  |  10   |  *The prices follow the data in the previous date (2019-01-01)
           A    | 2019-01-15  |  15   |      
           A    | 2019-01-25  |  20   |      
           A    | 2019-01-27  |  20   |  *The prices follow the data in the previous date (2019-01-25)
           A    | 2019-05-01  |  25   |      
           A    | 2019-07-02  |  30   |      
           B    | 2019-02-05  |  40   |
           B    | 2019-02-10  |  40   |  *The prices follow the data in the previous date (2019-02-05)
           B    | 2019-04-22  |  50   |      
           B    | 2019-05-12  |  40   |
           B    | 2019-05-13  |  40   |  *The prices follow the data in the previous date (2019-05-12)
```

NOTE:

- For **product A in Table B on 2018-11-05** not processed into results because there's no data before that date in the table A for that product.
- For **product B in Table B on 2019-04-22** not processed into results because the date and product in table A and B are the same (The data is already in table A)

**I try not to use looping mechanism because my data reaches millions**, but i was too dizzy to think about it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way is using `group by` in a cte and then `union`:

```
WITH cte AS(
SELECT b.product,
        b.[Date],
        MAX(a.[Date]) AS [DateValue]
FROM TableA AS a
INNER JOIN TableB AS b ON a.product = b.product
WHERE a.[Date] <= b.[Date]
GROUP BY b.product, b.[Date]
)
SELECT *
FROM dbo.TableA AS a
UNION
SELECT b.product,
        b.[Date],
        a.Price
FROM cte AS c
INNER JOIN dbo.TableB AS b ON b.product = c.product AND b.[Date] = c.[Date]
INNER JOIN dbo.TableA AS a ON a.product = c.product AND a.[Date] = c.[DateValue]
ORDER BY product, [Date]
```

Answer (score 3):

One method uses `union all` and `cross apply`:

```
select ab.product, ab.date, p.price
from ((select a.product, a.date
       from a
      ) union   -- intentional to remove duplicates
      (select b.product b.date
       from b
      )
     ) ab cross apply
     (select top (1) a.price
      from a
      where a.product = ab.product and a.date <= ab.date
      order by ab.date desc
     ) p;
```

Note that `cross apply` will eliminate the rows from `b` that have no price.

If SQL support the `ignore nulls` option on either `last_value()` or `lag()`, this would be more appropriate with a `full join`:

```
select coalesce(a.product, b.product) as product, 
       coalesce(a.date, b.date) as date,
       coalesce(a.price,
                lag(ignore nulls a.price) over (partition by coalesce(a.product, b.product) order by coalesce(a.date, b.date)) as price
from a full join
     b
     on a.product = b.product and a.date = b.date;
```

Alas, SQL Server does not (currently) support that.  You can make that work with a bit of effort and additional subqueries.

Comment: there is an error showing "The multi-part identifier "ab.product" could not be bound." - something related to "ab" has error. thanks btw for answering.

Comment: your answer is correct but it takes more time to process compared to the answer from cte6. btw thanks, upvoted

Comment: @Fadly . . . Thank you for the information.  If you want a faster version, you might ask another question.

Answer (score 1):

SQL MERGE is a very powerful tool to perform "CRUD" operation based on some condition...

Please follow the link for more details of this feature.

http://www.sqlservertutorial.net/sql-server-basics/sql-server-merge/

https://www.essentialsql.com/introduction-merge-statement/

Please feel free to ask if you have any doubt.